# Random Movement for UIImage not working

Tags: uiimage, game-physics, pong, arc4random

I started a tutorial for making a Ping Pong game and I reach the part where the ball should move randmoly but in my game the ball just goes up or down and shakes weird. Here is the code for the ball movement

```
-(IBAction)StartPoint:(id)sender
{

    Y = arc4random() %11;
    Y = Y - 5;

    X = arc4random() %11;
    X = X - 5;

    if (Y == 0) 
    {
        Y = 1;
    }

    if (X == 0) 
    {
        X = 1;
    }



    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 
                                             target:self     
                                           selector:@selector(BallMovement) 
                                           userInfo:nil 
                                            repeats:YES];
}

-(void)BallMovement{
    ball.center = CGPointMake(ball.center.x + X, ball.center.y + Y);

    if (ball.center.x < 15) 
    {
        X = 0 - X;
    }

    if (ball.center.x < 305) 
    {
        X = 0 - X;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay I fixed the shaking problem and the ball now moves randomly in X, but now i need to make it bounce with the borders.

```
-(IBAction)StartPoint:(id)sender{

Y = arc4random() %11;
Y = Y - 5;

X = arc4random() %9;
X = X - 5;

if (Y == 0) {
    Y = 1;
}

if (X == 0) {
    X = 1;
}



timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(BallMovement) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; }
```

I remove the code from this part:

```
-(void)BallMovement 
{ 
ball.center = CGPointMake(ball.center.x + X, ball.center.y + Y);
```

//I remove the conditions of this part and the movement of the ball got fix.

```
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This. This is Bouncing Ball effect it movies it different Directions**

```
-(void)onTimer 
{
ball.center = CGPointMake(ball.center.x+pos.x,ball.center.y+pos.y);

if(ball.center.x > 320 || ball.center.x < 0)

pos.x = -pos.x;

if(ball.center.y > 460 || ball.center.y < 0)

pos.y = -pos.y;

}


-(your method)

{

 pos = CGPointMake(14.0,7.0);

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(onTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}
```

Comment: But how should I declare the variable pos?

Comment: ok i tried. but it crash and sents me to:                            int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}